# Differenza tra "di" e "da"

Tags: difference, prepositions

Una cosa che non ho mai capito in italiano è la differenza tra "di" e "da". Per esempio, se si va in Italia si vedono molti ristoranti con il nome come "trattoria da Luca" "ristorante da Carlone", ma per come la vedo io dovrebbe essere "di Luca" visto che la trattoria è di Luca. Scusate per qualche sbaglio, sto ancora imparando.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @Enthusiast!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certo, “la trattoria di Luca” è corretto, ma ha un significato diverso.

Come avrai già notato, la preposizione “da” ha molti usi, oltre ai più frequenti come il moto da luogo («vengo da Roma») e il complemento d'agente («sono stato pizzicato dalle zanzare»). Vari altri li trovi per esempio [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/da/), tra cui quello che ci interessa:

> Con verbi di quiete (compl. di stato in luogo), si adopera per lo più davanti a nomi di persona: *sono stato dall’avvocato*; *ti attendo dal meccanico*; *mi servo dal droghiere qui di fronte*; *frequenta l’asilo dalle suore*; *sarò a cena da mio zio*; *da noi non c’è quest’uso* (in questi ultimi casi equivale in genere a: «presso»)

Si tratta cioè di un caso particolare dello stato in luogo, che fa riferimento alla casa, al negozio, al locale di qualcuno. Tra gli esempi del Treccani non ce ne sono con nomi propri, ma è molto usato anche così: «Stasera ci si vede da Mario».

E quindi i ristoranti e simili con nomi del tipo “Da Luca” si richiamano a questo uso di “da”, che tende anche a suggerire che quella trattoria sia accogliente e familiare, quasi come se si andasse “da Luca” nel senso di “a casa di Luca”.

Comment: L'uso è il corrispondente del francese *chez*

Answer (score -1):

L'esempio classico è "occhiali da sole" vs. "occhiali di sole" (quest'ultimo è strano; il sole non possiede occhiali!).

cf. "11.28 Da with complements of characteristic (‘typical of ’,
‘characteristic of ’,‘associated with’,‘characterized by’),
or purpose (‘intended for’,‘to be -ed’)" di [*A Reference Grammar of Modern Italian*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7277).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Io non ho votato, ma sono d'accordo: il "da" di "occhiali da sole" è diverso da "sono andate da sole" ed è diverso da "vieni da me".

Comment: @Geremia I didn't downvote, but I see nothing strange: “ristorante da Luca” and “occhiali da sole” are completely different contexts. The question asks for the differences between “da” and “di”; this is a case in which “di” makes no sense, so even under this respect the answer is low level.

Comment: @egreg "_this is a case in which 'di' makes no sense_" Sure, but it's still grammatically correct.